# How to call tool functions in PaperJS with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d, paperjs

I'm trying to call `onMouseDown`, `onMouseDrag` and `onMouseUp` functions from a vanilla javascript implementation of [PaperJS](http://paperjs.org/reference/toolevent/).

The following is not triggered:

```
// As in the docs
function onMouseDrag ( ev ) { ... }
```

Something else I tried (with rough implementation for context):

```
// My implmentation
var p = new paper.PaperScope(window);
p.setup( el );

// does not work
p.onMouseDrag = function ( ev ) { ... };
```

How do I access these global functions when not working in paperscope?

Comment: why cant you use the "function onMouseDrag(parameter)" in Potential event binding??

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa `function onMouseDrag(parameter)` is not triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer on the [PaperJS docs](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/#working-with-tools) that uses the following code:

```
var tool = new Tool();

// works
tool.onMouseDown = function( ev ) { ... }
tool.onMouseDrag = function( ev ) { ... }
```